# PhoneNumber Verification and Recaptcha Disable Issue- 2024

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have already added SHA1 and SHA256 in my Firebase project's general settings, but I am still facing an issue where I get redirected to the Recaptcha page in my Expo React Native app during phone number verification.

Despite following the Firebase documentation and ensuring the SHA certificates are correctly added, the problem persists. Below is a snippet of my code where I initialize Firebase and handle phone number verification.

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^3.3.2",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "7.2.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^18.8.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^18.8.0",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "2.4.10",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.9",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.7",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.17",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.0.1",
    "axios": "^1.6.5",
    "expo": "~49.0.8",
    "expo-dev-client": "~2.4.13",
    "expo-font": "~11.4.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~14.3.2",
    "expo-secure-store": "~12.3.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.20.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "lottie-react-native": "5.1.6",
    "memoize": "^10.0.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.49.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.10",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.10.4",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.3.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
    "react-native-youtube-iframe": "^2.3.0",
    "react-redux": "^9.0.4",
    "swr": "^2.2.4",
    "yup": "^1.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from": "^7.18.9",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.4.9"
  },
```

```
 const signInWithPhoneNumber = async (phoneNumber) => {
    try {
      const confirmation = await auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
      setConfirm(confirmation);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Invalid code.", error);
      dispatch(
        showSnackbar({
          message:
            "Failed to verify phone number. Please try again later or contact support.",
          type: "error",
        })
      );
    }
  };

  const resendCode = async () => {
    try {
      const confirmation = await auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(
        registerUser?.phone,
        true
      );
      setConfirm(confirmation);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Invalid code.", error);
      dispatch(
        showSnackbar({
          message: "Failed to resend OTP.",
          type: "error",
        })
      );
    }
  };

  const handleVerifyCode = async () => {
    try {
      dispatch(startLoading());
      const otpCode = otp.join("");
      const result = await confirm.confirm(otpCode);
      if (result.user && Object.keys(registerUser).length !== 0) {
        const userData = {
          ...registerUser,
          fireBaseSessionId: result?.user?.uid,
          verifyWith: "phone",
        };
        const response = await instance.post("/api/user", userData);

        if (response?.status === 201) {
          const { details, token } = response?.data;
          dispatch(setCurrentUser(details));
          await SecureStore.setItemAsync("token", JSON.stringify(token));
          dispatch(
            setTokens({
              accessToken: token.accessToken,
              refreshToken: token.refreshToken,
            })
          );
          navigation.navigate("Home");
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch(
        showSnackbar({
          message: error?.response?.message || error?.message || error,
          type: "error",
        })
      );
      console.log("Invalid code.", error?.message) || error;
    } finally {
      dispatch(stopLoading());
    }
  };

  const onSubmit = async (data) => {
    dispatch(startLoading());
    const newUser = {
      ...data,
      country: selectedCountry,
    };
    try {
      setRegisterUser(newUser);
      await signInWithPhoneNumber(data.phone);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Sign-up error:", error.message);
    } finally {
      dispatch(stopLoading());
    }
  };
```

Comment: You do not need to quote your own original text, and **bold** is to be used only to emphasize specific words or phrases, not the entire text of your post. Not over-using formatting makes your post easier to read and understand. And the use of *issue* in your title is meaningless, as everything that goes wrong is an *issue*, so it's far too vague. You'll find your experiences at SO will be much better if you take the time to go through the [tour] and read the [help] pages, especially [ask], to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Expo, I would encourage you to follow the React Native Firebase [documentation for the Expo Managed Workflow](https://rnfirebase.io/#expo) and let the Expo build system deal with all the native muckity-muck for you.

Comment: Thank you for your responce , "I've already integrated everything into my Expo React Native managed project (Android), and the OTP is working fine. However, I want to disable the reCAPTCHA redirections in my development server. I found a solution by adding a phone number as a test number in Firebase settings, but I want to disable this reCAPTCHA process without adding test numbers. I'm also unsure how to handle this scenario in production. Any advice?"